# Android : Network on main thread exception even when using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am working on an Android project and for Login I am communicating with the server for authentication. Even though I am using AsyncTask, I am getting NetworkOnMain thread exception. Why is that. Here is my code :

```
public class Login extends Activity {

    public static RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    Button loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LoginButton);
        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!(v == null)) {
                    EditText userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameText);
                    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.PasswordField);
                    if (!(userEmail.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {
                        if (!(userPassword.getText().toString().isEmpty())) {
                            loginUserViaRest(userEmail.getText().toString(), userPassword.getText().toString());
                            if (!(StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid == null)) {
                                if (!(StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid.isEmpty())) {

                                    executeRestLogin executeRestLogin = new executeRestLogin();
                                    executeRestLogin.doInBackground();

 private class executeRestLogin extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid);
            HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);

// Below line gives me an error
            HttpEntity<String> rssResponse = rest.exchange(
                    "http://192.168.178.60:8080/dashboard",
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    requestEntity,
                    String.class);
            StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid = rssResponse.getBody();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong. Also, how can I get custom objects back as response from async task?

*Update*

To the next problem in question :

```
  ExecuteRestLogin executeRestLogin = new ExecuteRestLogin();
// The below execute method works, but I cannot get the result of postExecute in it, it shows me its not of the type Void, Void, String. 
 String result =  executeRestLogin.execute();

private class ExecuteRestLogin extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid);
            HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);

            HttpEntity<String> rssResponse = rest.exchange(
                    "http://192.168.178.60:8080/dashboard",
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    requestEntity,
                    String.class);
            StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid = rssResponse.getBody();
            return StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Implement `onPostExecute(.... )`.. refer this [tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-asynctask-example/)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> executeRestLogin.doInBackground();
> ```

Call `execute()` to execute an async task on a background thread. Calling `doInBackground()` directly just runs the method on your current thread.

> how can I get custom objects back as response from async task

Put the code that deals with async task results in `onPostExecute()`. It gets run on the UI thread.

Comment: So I have to create a new thread like Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable( ) ), and inside this call the doInBackground method, but then I can call the actual code directly in thread, why should I have to deal with all these nuances of AsyncTask then?

Comment: No. Just replace your `doInBackground()` call with `execute()`. The async task framework will take it from there.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But I am unable to get the result in PostExecute. I have updated my code in the main post. Can you have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling *doInBackground* form the UI therad!
In order to start an *AsyncTask* you need to call *execute*.
**executeRestLogin.execute()**

Edit:

Dont forget conventions a class starts with an upper case.

Call execute on the AysnTask object will start the task. This [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example) will make it clearer.

Comment: It expects a Runnable object, so do I have to create a new Thread? Then what's the point of using Async because I can do already all this stuff within a Thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the **doInBackground()** by **execute()**. With that the code in doInBackground method will be executed in another thread.(you should not create a new thread, Android does it for you.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like:

```
private class ExecuteRestLogin extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Boolean> {
 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.add("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid);
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestHeaders);

        HttpEntity<String> rssResponse = rest.exchange(
                "http://192.168.178.60:8080/dashboard",
                HttpMethod.GET,
                requestEntity,
                String.class);
        StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid = rssResponse.getBody();
        result = StaticRestTemplate.jsessionid; // result is a global String.
        return true;
    }

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
         if (success) {
            //You can use your result string now.
        }
    }
}
```